# Does message passing become sequential when many processors send to a specific processor at the same time?

Tags: mpi

When many processors send data to a specific processor at the same time, are they copied sequentially? For example,

```
if(rank==1)
    MPI_Send(&message, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(rank==0)
    MPI_Recv(&message, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Let `T` be the time required for this execution.Then, what is the required time for the following code?

```
MPI_Gather(&message,1,MPI_DOUBLE,messages,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

where `n-1` processors try to send a message to the master node and I have `128` processors.  Is it `T` or `127*T`?

Comment: You should show more code, your question looks like a nonsense. The code on that receiving processor is important and you have to place the `Recv()`s correcponding to the Send you have shown somehow. They can be in different threads or in one serial code. You could also have non-blocking communication (`ISend`, `IRecv`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question shows you are still confused. `MPI_Gather()` is not just a sequence of messages. Therefore your question without mentioning you actually meant the Gather didn't make any sense.

MPI_Send and MPI_Recv are point 2 point communications, but MPI_Gather is a collective procedure. The MPI library has a special implementation that can avoid implementing it naively as a sequence of sends to the target process.

You can read in the article http://cursuri.cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/mpi/impl/wmpi/docs/WMPI_EuroPVMMPI99_Silva.pdf how the collectives can be implemented for high performance.